# Why can't I divide a datetime.timedelta by a float?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now1 = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now2 = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> timedelta = now2-now1
>>> halfdt = timedelta/2  #This works just fine
>>> halfdt = timedelta/2. #TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'float'
```

Does anybody know the rational for only allowing timedeltas to be divisible by integers?

Comment: @Woobie -- You're correct.  I hadn't tried that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple - it was a missing feature.

The upside of this is that it's been added as a feature in Python 3.x.

Note the difference between the supported operation tables in [2.x](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) and [3.x](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/datetime.html).

Comment: Thanks.  I was just floored when it didn't work, and I was wondering if there was any rational behind it.  Since it works in python 3.x, I'll assume you're right and it was just an oversight.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, floor it, and try again! *chuckle.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting -- I would have expected that to work too. I just wrote a function with some examples/doctests that does this in Python 2.x. Also posted as an [ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578136-function-that-supports-dividing-timedelta-by-float/):

```
import datetime

def divide_timedelta(td, divisor):
    """Python 2.x timedelta doesn't support division by float, this function does.

    >>> td = datetime.timedelta(10, 100, 1000)
    >>> divide_timedelta(td, 2) == td / 2
    True
    >>> divide_timedelta(td, 100) == td / 100
    True
    >>> divide_timedelta(td, 0.5)
    datetime.timedelta(20, 200, 2000)
    >>> divide_timedelta(td, 0.3)
    datetime.timedelta(33, 29133, 336667)
    >>> divide_timedelta(td, 2.5)
    datetime.timedelta(4, 40, 400)
    >>> td / 0.5
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      ...
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'float'

    """
    # timedelta.total_seconds() is new in Python version 2.7, so don't use it
    total_seconds = (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 1e6) / 1e6
    divided_seconds = total_seconds / float(divisor)
    return datetime.timedelta(seconds=divided_seconds)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is different to Python 3.x's functionality, as far as I can tell, as Python 3.x does '[Delta divided by a float or an int. The result is rounded to the nearest multiple of timedelta.resolution using round-half-to-even.](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/datetime.html)', and yours doesn't use the resolution, so it's not quite a drop-in replacement. Still useful, however, so +1.

Comment: Fair call -- I don't suppose you could suggest edits to fix this? (Assuming it's simple enough -- I think this is enough of an edge case that it probably doesn't matter much.)